# Android ListView : changing dataset and calling notifyDataSetChanged inside of getView

Tags: java, android, listview

I have a `ListView` that displays ads. Sometimes the ads cannot be generated and I have nothing to display in the list item where there would usually be ads. The ads are generated inside of the list adapter callback `getView`.

Basically I want to remove an item from the `ListView` dataset during the call to get view for that item. Is this possible? Currently removing the item from the data set and calling `notifyDataSetChanged` continues to the render the item. Is there anyway to achieve this?

My main question is really ... Does calling `onNotifyDataSetChanged()` have any affect during a call to `getView`?

Comment: I think you should change your approach to render ListView. ListView getView method is called by the adapter to get a view so that it can render. You should not write your business logic there. Please re check whether you can write the logic of creating ads outside getView method.

Comment: yeah, it does affects, by calling notifydataSet(), it will call your getView() method again, you can put a breakpoint and check.

Answer (score 1):

Yes it is possible and you can use arraylist  and remove the item of that position from arraylist and just call notifyDataSetChanged anywhere in the adapter class

Comment: can you post your adapter class

Comment: I wish ... it's like 800 LOC ... probably not.

Answer (score 1):

Normally, your dataset is passed as parameter on your adapter class when you instantiate your adapter. You could delete any data on it inside adapter class. And `NotifyDataSetChanged()` could be called in your method from adapter class.

Comment: Yeah my main question is really ... Does calling `onNotifyDataSetChanged()` have any affect during a call to `getView`?